# TypeError: data.map is not a function in react

Tags: reactjs, api, dictionary, axios

I try to map data in react like

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/books').then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
            setData(res.data)
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
    
    {data.map(book => (
                <h1>{book.title}</h1>
            ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

in console data show like

```
{data: Array(100)}
data
: 
(100) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, ]
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

the error is [image] how to solve this issue i try many ways  but not working please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`console.log(res.data)` shows it has a data object which consists the array. So you should set like `setData(res.data.data)`. Currently you are setting the object, which cannot be used with `map`

Answer (score 1):

You can see the console the data is {data: Array(100)}

so you need to update the state like

```
  setData(res.data.data)
```